# What to do when you encounter a user whose posts are all bad?

Tags: discussion

The other day I was looking through questions and ended up on a question where a user was asking about a very basic programming concept.  Not that those questions are necessarily bad, but this one made me wonder "How is this person even programming at all?"  So on a whim, I checked out their profile.

What I found was not good.  They had a handful of questions, ranging from code-dumps, give me teh codez, explain me this and off-topic questions.  My initial reaction was to start doling out the downvotes / close votes to make it all go away.  But then my brain caught up with me and said "You shouldn't be serial downvoting a user.  Don't start a witch hunt."

Now I'm stuck.  I want to get rid of the bad posts, but I also don't want to target this user.  Should I start trying to clean this up or just walk away?

(I tried to search through meta for an answer, but including the terms "down vote", "close vote", "serial downvotes" bring up almost every meta post ever.)

Comment: Carry on about your business - nothing unusual to see here:(

Comment: Vote to close, flag for mod attention explaining how most if not all the posts from said user should be removed for -explain your reasons-

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your gut is right; don't start a witch hunt for this user.  The posts you encounter *naturally* are likely fine to vote on, but you could be seen as serial voting if you start going through this person's profile just to downvote their posts.

Let 'em be; the system will catch up to them soon enough.  Others have likely seen their content and would vote the same way as you.

Comment: *Let 'em be; the system will catch up to them soon enough* We hope.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  Better to *hope* that the system will catch up with them than be *assured* that the system will catch up with you if you serial downvote them, as tempting as it may be.

Comment: Agree.  I just hope enough people will vote the same way so the system does catch them.  I totally agree with you that it is not okay to target a user.

Comment: We hope = we must assume; we must assume that we're not alone on SO trying to do the right thing and thus can freely choose our actions based on that assumption, such as simply letting things go after we did our tiny but relevant contribution. I mean the alternative is that we actually are alone, and at that point its time to mosey on to greener pastures rather than trying to be the lone ranger in the wild west.

Answer (score 6):

> I want to get rid of the bad posts, but I also don't want to target this user. Should I start trying to clean this up or just walk away?

You have to walk away.  As you noted, targeting a user (even if that's not the intent) is serial voting.  Regardless if a user's posts are all good or bad, serial voting skews the community's assessment of their contributions and breaks the voting system.  Just stick to voting on the original post and let the community take care of business.  If nothing else, their posts will just be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's a couple of duplicates of this question, but in common: flag for moderator attention and specifically describe the behavior you see.

Sure, there are automated systems, and you can have faith in the voting and flagging patterns of your fellow users, but in the meantime the user in question will continue asking poor questions that basically waste the time of everyone involved.

If you're correct and there's a user who repeatedly show that they can't properly ask questions, take action to let the behavior end as soon as possible. Flag.

Comment: What good would flagging to, exactly?  It isn't like they've done something that a moderator *absolutely* must intervene in.

Comment: Moderators can hand out bans, when appropriate, right?

Comment: They can hand out bans when the behavior is egregious and isn't something that the community can directly deal with.  A user posting crappy answers shouldn't rise to the occasion of moderators; the community and the systems in place *will* eventually deal with it.

Comment: And it's exactly the "eventually" part that would cause _me_ to flag for moderator attention. I trust the system, but humans more.

Comment: I'm not saying you should flag lightly. When you spot a user that you think the system should have caught, but hasn't (lots of poor questions without any down-, up- or closevotes), as far as I'm concerned it's fine flagging that user. Like I said, they're wasting everyone's time and not creating content that's useful for others, so I wouldn't mind involving a moderator in that.

Comment: This is supported by [Jeff's answer at "How should we respond to persistently low quality question askers?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62685/), but that's quite an old post and I'm not sure that current SO moderators actually still suspend for ["persistent low-quality contribution"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136897/what-is-the-criteria-for-the-user-never-gives-anything-back-to-the-community?lq=1) (as I believe it was called).